# update on merMod object gives different fit

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to refit a full model of class `merMod` with just the intercept (the null model). However, refitting using `update.merMod` gives a different answer than fitting the null model by hand, e.g.:

```
# Generate random data
set.seed(9)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = do.call(c, lapply(1:5, function(x) rnorm(100, x))),
  random = letters[1:5]
)

dat$y = rnbinom(500, mu = exp(dat$x), size = 1)

library(lme4)

# Get full model
full <- glmer.nb(y ~ x + (1 | random), dat)

# Write out intercept-only model by hand
null <- glmer.nb(y ~ 1 + (1 | random), dat)

# Update 
null2 <- update(full, . ~ 1 -. + (1 | random))

VarCorr(null)

VarCorr(null2)
```

Any idea why this is an how I can use `update` to get the same vcov matrix?

Comment: Specifying the formula and building a new model instead of using update works:
`
f <- paste(all.vars.trans(formula(full))[1], " ~ 1 + ", onlyBars(formula(full)));

null3 <- glmer.nb(formula(f), dat);

VarCorr(null3)
`
So I assume this is an issue with the environment?

Comment: The update method uses the theta value from the full model, whereas in the null model it is reestimated. I thought there may be a way to specify initCtrl to force a new estimatin of theta, but i cant get the arguemnt to be recognised at all.

Comment: Yes I thought that too, i also tried nb.control but that also did not work.

Comment: It's not really a solution but maybe it helps that you can specify an equal theta value for the two methods `null2 <- update(full, .~. -x, family = family(null))`